# Get Input in Div with Starting-ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to select a Input inside a Div which has a dynamic id (`[id^="SML_ID_"]`) is it possible to archive it?

My Example-Code is this:

```
$('[id^="SML_ID_"] .social_media_input_type').on("change", function() {
        var Link_ID = $('[id^="SML_ID_"]').attr("id");
        var Link_Type = $("SML_ID_" + Link_ID + " > social_media_input_type").text();
        Link_ID.replace("SML_ID_", "");
        $("SML_ID_" + Link_ID).text("Input a" + Link_Type + "link");
    });
```

Any Idea?

EDIT:

HTML-Structure:

```
var Link_ID = 0;
    $("#AddSocialMediaLink").on("click", function() {
        Link_ID = Link_ID + 1;
        var AddSML_HTML_String = '<div id="SML_ID_' + Link_ID + '" class = "social_media">\n\
                                <input class="social_media_input_type" type="text" placeholder="Input a Type!"/>\n\
                                <input class="social_media_input_link" name="" placeholder="Input a link" / >\n\
                        </div><br/>';
        $("#social_media_form").prepend(AddSML_HTML_String);
    })
```

Comment: What do you mean by "archive it"?

Comment: whats the question/problem?

Comment: And can you show the HTML structure?

Comment: I want to track if the Input-field is changed

Comment: @jmar777 it is dynamic created, added to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use delegation by attaching to a container

```
$(document).on('change','[id^="SML_ID_"] .social_media_input_type', function() {
        var Link_ID = $('[id^="SML_ID_"]').attr("id");
        var Link_Type = $("SML_ID_" + Link_ID + " > social_media_input_type").text();
    Link_ID.replace("SML_ID_", "");
    $("SML_ID_" + Link_ID).text("Input a" + Link_Type + "link");
});
```